# Soma dos numeros inteiros de 1 à 100

Tags: lógica, visualg, pseudocódigo, programação-estruturada

Estou tentando criar um algoritmo que some os números do intervalo 1-100. Além disso o programa imprime cada elemento da soma e no final o resultado.

Ou seja, 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6...

Importante: Utilizando pseudo-linguagem (portugol). Porém estou fazendo algo de errado na minha lógica e o resultado não corresponde a realidade.

O que seria?

```
    Var
// Seção de Declarações das variáveis 
   numero, soma, index : inteiro

Inicio
// Seção de Comandos, procedimento, funções, operadores, etc... 
   numero <- 1
   index <- 2
   escreva (numero, " + ")
   soma <- numero + index
   enquanto (index < 101) faca
            numero <- numero + 1
            index <- index + 1
            escreva (numero, " + ")
            soma <- soma + index
   fimenquanto
   escreva ("A soma dos inteiros de 1 à 100 é: ", soma)
Fimalgoritmo
```

Como resposta ao código acima o VisualG entrega:

```
 1 +  2 +  3 +  4 +  5 +  6 +  7 +  8 +  9 +  10 +  11 +  12 +  13 +  14 +  15 +  16 +  17 +  18 +  19 +  20 +  21 +  22 +  23 +  24 +  25 +  26 +  27 +  28 +  29 +  30 +  31 +  32 +  33 +  34 +  35 +  36 +  37 +  38 +  39 +  40 +  41 +  42 +  43 +  44 +  45 +  46 +  47 +  48 +  49 +  50 +  51 +  52 +  53 +  54 +  55 +  56 +  57 +  58 +  59 +  60 +  61 +  62 +  63 +  64 +  65 +  66 +  67 +  68 +  69 +  70 +  71 +  72 +  73 +  74 +  75 +  76 +  77 +  78 +  79 +  80 +  81 +  82 +  83 +  84 +  85 +  86 +  87 +  88 +  89 +  90 +  91 +  92 +  93 +  94 +  95 +  96 +  97 +  98 +  99 +  100 + A soma dos inteiros de 1 à 100 é:  5151
```

Comment: Qual o resultado que está saindo? Porque `index` é 2? Pelo que vejo `numero` e `index` poderiam ser uma mesma variável

Comment: Que tal isso? `escreva("A soma dos inteiros de 1 à 100 é: 5050")`

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tem variável demais e algumas coisas que não fazem sentido. É simples, escreva o número, some ele e incremente para ir para o próximo.

```
Var
    soma, index : inteiro
Inicio
    index <- 1
    soma <- 0
    enquanto (index < 101) faca
        escreva (index, " + ")
        soma <- soma + index
        index <- index + 1
    fimenquanto
    escreva ("A soma dos inteiros de 1 à 100 é: ", soma)
Fimalgoritmo
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Portugol/Sum.ptg).

Answer (score 1):

Obrigado! Havia acabado de conseguir quando sua msg chegou. Deixarei abaixo como ficou minha resolução e desculpe pela pergunta trivial.

```
Var
   numero, soma: inteiro
Inicio
      numero <- 0
      soma <- 0
      enquanto (numero < 100) faca
               numero <- numero + 1
               soma <- soma + numero
               se (numero = 100) entao
                  escreval (numero)
               senao
                    escreva (numero, " + ")
               fimse
      fimenquanto
      escreva ("A soma dos inteiros de 1 à 100 é", soma)
Fimalgoritmo
```

Answer (score 0):

```
algoritmo "somados100numerosinteiros"
var soma,cont, index:inteiro
inicio
soma <- 0
cont <- 1

escreva (cont, " + ")
enquanto (cont<101) faca
soma <- soma + cont
cont <- cont + 1
index <- index + 1
escreva (cont, " + ")
fimenquanto
escreval ("0 = ",soma)
fimalgoritmo
```